# How to use "am start" command without starting UI

Tags: android, shell

I would like to know how do I start an application without starting UI. For example I use this command:

```
am start com.package.name/.MainActivity
```

But this command also starts the UI. Sorry for my bad english :) Thank you all your answers.

Answer (score 0):

Android applications without UI are usually services, you can start a service using the following shell command:

```
adb shell am startservice -n packageName/.ServiceClass
```

Comment: In my case, the application comes with an UI which I want to hide. Using `startservice` on such app yields to `Error: Not found; no service started`